# Scatter plot line becomes a light line if crowded

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

The scatter plot if having different classes in y axes. The class that is crowded (having 99% values) becomes really light.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
sns.scatterplot(x='Time',data=df,y='Class',hue='Class')
plt.show()
```

[image: Scatter Plot]

Comment: What would you expect?  Do you have some transparency set? What do you want to show to your readers?  Maybe `sns.stripplot(x='Time', data=df, y='Class', hue='Class', orient='h', s=3, jitter=0.4, alpha=1)`?

Comment: Excellent, this is one level above what I am expecting. And I will be using this going forward. But just curious I tried to set alpha=1 and my assumption is that there will be no transparency if alpha=1. So, why does 2 overlapping bright points make it lighter.

Comment: It's because of the white edges. Though if they weren't there, it would just be a blue line...

Comment: Thanks, got it. By the way how did you find its the edge color that's creating problem? I just want to know your process.

Comment: That's what I set it to when I wrote the function.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by mwaskom in the comments, it is because of white edges.
make the attribute edgecolors to none to remove the fading effect.

```
edgecolors=None
```